# Setting up SQL Express on Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machine, powershell, sql-server, azure

I'm trying to set up SQL express on an Azure VM. I already have SSMS 2012 installed but I cannot access `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

[This MSDN discussion says](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/cf9f458b-dc59-4759-bf32-318f6d7a37b2/installing-sql-server-express-on-azure-virtual-machine-for-vs-2013?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows):

> run powershell script "ConfigureSQLExpress.ps1" under "C:\ConfigureDeveloperDesktop\Scripts\" to complete the configuration.

I looked in this folder but no such file exists.

Where can I download this script file; or what is a better technique for downloading this?